# Remove mark from gutter in Sublime Text

Tags: windows, windows-10, sublimetext3

Is there any way to remove the mark from gutter. You can set mark with command/shortcut `"keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+space"], "command": "set_mark"`, but I cant find command to remove it. Is there any way to remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing the mark is available from the Edit menu -> Mark -> Clear Mark, which executes:

`command: clear_bookmarks {"name": "mark"}`

(as can be seen with `sublime.log_commands()` in the ST console, or by viewing the main menu file in the Default package)
This is bound to <kbd>Ctrl+K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd> by default.